# Ionic Cordova Build Android - CordovaLib:generateDebugRFile FAILED

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I am new to programming on Ionic. I am on Ionic version 5.4.16, and I am trying to build my Ionic Angular app that has been integrated with Cordova for Android. In the terminal in the root of my app, I type `ionic cordova build android`, but I cannot get my app to build. The app builds up to a certain point, but crashes with the following error:

```
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugRFile FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':CordovaLib:generateDebugRFile' (type 'GenerateLibraryRFileTask').
> File 'C:\Projects\MyApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\local_only_symbol_list\debug\R-def.txt' specified for property 'localResourcesFile' does not exist.
```

Any support would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: what version of Java JDK are you using? also share your cordova and Ionic version. try command `ionic info` and share details.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. I am using Java verison 1.8.0_261. I am on Ionic version 5.4.16, and on Cordova version 10.0.0. I am not sure if this is important, but when I typed `ionic info` into my project directory it said `cordova-res : not installed` under the Utility category.

Comment: You can install it from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-res But i think it will not resolve your issue.